# Change countdown when refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, html, date, timer, countdown

I have my own webshop and on the home page i have a lot of products with countdown.

So whats the problem?
The problem is, when i have many javascripts on home page then the broser will freezing, getting slow.

How i know this is an javascript problem ? I tried to disable javascript on the browser and my website works normal.

```
/*!
 *
 * Brian2000: BK_Countdown v1.1
 * AKA: Brian's jQuery Robust Date/Time Countdown
 * http://brian2000.com
 *
 * Copyright 2012-2013, Brian Kennedy
 * Licensed under the GPL Version 3 license
 * http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.en.html
 *
 * Date: Wed Jan 9 2013 2:54PM EST  
 *
 * You can't remove this part, and if you make changes or improve things, please keep me informed.
 * Thank you, enjoy, and support Open Source!
 */

/*
    This portion explains how to use the counter, I recomend not deleting it either ;-)

    VARS [required]
    ------------------------------------------------
    container: ID of Element for counter
    targetDate: MM/DD/YYYY
    targetTime: HH:MM:SS (0-23 Hour) [seconds are optional]

    OPTIONS:
    ------------------------------------------------
    order: format/output order 
            order: 1 = Label + Spacer + Value
            order: 2 = Value + Spacer + Label (reverse from order 1)
    spacer: text/string seperator between label and value   
    element: html element for label and value containers (default is span)
    end: Message to display when date has passed
    dayOf: Message to display on day of counter expiration


*/
function BK_CountDown(container, targetDate, targetTime, opts) {
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //vars
    this.opts = opts;
    this.complete = false; //for exiting interval
    this.container = container; //target

    DArray = targetDate.split('/'); 
    this.targetDate = DArray[0] + '/' + DArray[1] + '/' + DArray[2];

    TArray = targetTime.split(':');
    this.targetHour = TArray[0]; //hr
    this.targetMin = TArray[1]; //min
    if (typeof TArray[2] == 'undefined') { //sec
      this.targetSec = 0;
    }else{
        this.targetSec = TArray[2];
    }   
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // options
    var defaults = {
        'order'     :       "1",
        'spacer'    :       ':',
        'element'   :       'span',
        'end'       :       "Deal is ended!",
        'dayOf'     :       "Deal is ended!"
    }
    if(typeof this.opts != "undefined") { //if options were assigned...
        for(var i in defaults) { //assign defaults for unchanged opts
            if(typeof this.opts[i] == "undefined") {
                this.opts[i] = defaults[i];
            }
        }
    }else{ //no options were assigned
        this.opts = defaults;
    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////


    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////  assembly                  
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    s = this.opts['spacer'];
    this.c = container.substring(1);
    e = this.opts['element'];
    if(this.opts['order'] == 2){
    //reverse assembly
        $(container).append('<' + e + ' id="' + this.c + '_count_days" class="count_days"></' + e + '>');       
        $(container).append('<' + e + ' id="' + this.c + '_txt_days" class="txt_days">' + s + ' Days</' + e + '>');
        $(container).append('<' + e + ' id="' + this.c + '_count_hours" class="count_hours"></' + e + '>');     
        $(container).append('<' + e + ' id="' + this.c + '_txt_hours" class="txt_hours">' + s + ' :</' + e + '>');
        $(container).append('<' + e + ' id="' + this.c + '_count_min" class="count_min"></' + e + '>');     
        $(container).append('<' + e + ' id="' + this.c + '_txt_min" class="txt_min">' + s + ' :</' + e + '>');

    }
    else{
    //default assembly
        $(container).append('<' + e + ' id="' + this.c + '_txt_days" class="txt_days">Days ' + s + '</' + e + '>');     
        $(container).append('<' + e + ' id="' + this.c + '_count_days" class="count_days"></' + e + '>');
        $(container).append('<' + e + ' id="' + this.c + '_txt_hours" class="txt_hours">Hours ' + s + '</' + e + '>');      
        $(container).append('<' + e + ' id="' + this.c + '_count_hours" class="count_hours"></' + e + '>');
        $(container).append('<' + e + ' id="' + this.c + '_txt_min" class="txt_min">Minutes ' + s + '</' + e + '>');        
        $(container).append('<' + e + ' id="' + this.c + '_count_min" class="count_min"></' + e + '>');

    }
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    ////////  Count Update function                 
    this.count_update = function count_update(){

        date = new Date(); //NOW
        targetDate = new Date(this.targetDate);
        targetDate.setHours(this.targetHour);
        targetDate.setMinutes(this.targetMin);
        targetDate.setSeconds(this.targetSec);

        var UDate =  Math.round(date.getTime()/1000);
        var UTargetDate =  Math.round(targetDate.getTime()/1000);

        differance = UTargetDate - UDate;

        days=Math.floor(differance/(60*60*24)*1);
        hours=Math.floor((differance%(60*60*24))/(60*60)*1);
        minutes=Math.floor(((differance%(60*60*24))%(60*60))/(60)*1);
        seconds=Math.floor((((differance%(60*60*24))%(60*60))%(60))*1);

        //if range is 0 don't display range
        //days
        if(days <= 0){$(this.container + '_count_days').remove();$(this.container + '_txt_days').remove();}
        else{$(this.container + '_count_days').text(days);}
        //hours
        if(days <= 0 && hours <= 0){$(this.container + '_count_hours').remove();$(this.container + '_txt_hours').remove();}
        else{$(this.container + '_count_hours').text(hours);}
        //min
        if(days <= 0 && hours <= 0 && minutes <= 0){$(this.container + '_count_min').remove();$(this.container + '_txt_min').remove();}
        else{$(this.container + '_count_min').text(+minutes);}
        //seconds
        $(this.container + '_count_sec').text(seconds);

        //Singular text for 'reverse' assembly
        if(this.opts['order'] == 2){
            if(days <= 1){$(this.container + '_txt_days').text(this.opts['spacer'] + ' dag en ');}
            else{$(this.container + '_txt_days').text(this.opts['spacer'] + ' dagen en ')}
            if(hours == 1){$(this.container + '_txt_hours').text(this.opts['spacer'] + ' uur en ');}
            else{$(this.container + '_txt_hours').text(this.opts['spacer'] + ' uur en ');}
            if(minutes == 1){$(this.container + '_txt_min').text(this.opts['spacer'] + ' min');}
            else{$(this.container + '_txt_min').text(this.opts['spacer'] + ' min');}
            if(seconds == 1){$(this.container + '_txt_sec').text(this.opts['spacer'] + '');}
            else{$(this.container + '_txt_sec').text(this.opts['spacer'] + '');}
        }

        //end of countdown
        if(days <= 0 && hours <= 0 && minutes <= 0 && seconds <= 0){
            //timer is over, final output
            //if date is today!
            if(new Date().toDateString() == targetDate.toDateString()){
                $(this.container).addClass('count_now');
                $(this.container).text(this.opts['dayOf']);
            }else{//if date is after today              
                $(this.container).addClass('count_end');
                $(this.container).text(this.opts['end']);
            }
            this.complete = true;
        }   
    };
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //run immediately
    this.count_update();

    //now loop this every second
    var selfobject = this; //scope gets lost within setInterval (see: http://www.vonloesch.de/node/32)
    var theCounter = setInterval(function(){
        selfobject.count_update();
            if(selfobject.complete == true){
                clearInterval(theCounter);}
        }, 1000);
}
```

HTML:

`$(document).ready(function() {

    var aanbiedingcountdown = new BK_CountDown('#deal1', '05/25/2014', '23:57', {order: 2, spacer: ''});
    var aanbiedingcountdown = new BK_CountDown('#deal2', '05/26/2014', '23:57', {order: 2, spacer: ''});
    var aanbiedingcountdown = new BK_CountDown('#deal3', '05/28/2014', '23:57', {order: 2, spacer: ''});
    var aanbiedingcountdown = new BK_CountDown('#deal4', '05/28/2014', '15:10', {order: 2, spacer: ''});
        var aanbiedingcountdown = new BK_CountDown('#deal5', '05/26/2014', '23:57', {order: 2, spacer: ''});
});`

You see, for every countdown that i want i need to create an ID.
But what i want is that when the page load, the countdown dont need to run, it makes my website slower. So, only when the someone refresh the page then he get the right date & time.

Example: Time is now 16:00u, the countdown are set at 17h, so, when someone is still on my website (10min) without refreshing the page then the countdown is still 16h only if he refresh the page then countdown is 16:10h...

I've seen this on other websites and they have more than 100 products with countdowns on the same page and still works perfect because timer is not running only if people refresh the page the the timer will set to right date & time.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uJk73/ (i removed seconds, i though site will go faster without this, but no succes)

Hope someone can help my with this.

Comment: Use one setInterval loop that controls all countdowns, and have it loop less frequently.

Comment: I would have to figure it out just as you would.

Comment: Yes i know, just the same Countdown ID's. But the problem is this: <span id="aanbiedingcountdown800_count_hours" class="count_hours">7</span>
<span id="aanbiedingcountdown800_txt_hours" class="txt_hours"> uur en </span>
<span id="aanbiedingcountdown800_count_min" class="count_min">34</span>
<span id="aanbiedingcountdown800_txt_min" class="txt_min"> min</span> This will show on every product and this makes my website slower.

Comment: It looks like you only need to remove `var theCounter = setInterval` and add a setInterval in global scope that runs `.count_update();` on each instance.

Comment: Ah, you're right, changing the HTML so many times is slow. You can speed up that part by using `.detach()` before the appends and adding the element back afterwards. But it only does that part once per item.

Comment: Dude, i don't know how i can give you some reputation... But your first answer has fix this, only i do this: this.count_update(); instead of .count... Now my website are works normal! Thanks! Then Span ID's doesn't change so i dont need to past the .detach code?

Comment: No, those appends only occur once per deal, no need to detach.

Answer (score 0):

[**Updated jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/uJk73/6/)

So let's say you had 9 deals

```
<div id="countdowntimer">
    <div id="deal1"></div>
    <div id="deal2"></div>
    <div id="deal3"></div>
    <div id="deal4"></div>
    <div id="deal5"></div>
    <div id="deal6"></div>
    <div id="deal7"></div>
    <div id="deal8"></div>
    <div id="deal9"></div>
</div>
```

Get rid of this loop in `BK_CountDown()`

```
//now loop this every second
/*var selfobject = this; //scope gets lost within setInterval (see: http://www.vonloesch.de/node/32)
var theCounter = setInterval(function(){
    selfobject.count_update();
        if(selfobject.complete == true){
            clearInterval(theCounter);}
    }, 1000);
    */
```

Then

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var deals = []; // create an array
    deals.push( new BK_CountDown('#deal1', '05/24/2014', '23:59', {order: 2, spacer: ''}) );  
    deals.push( new BK_CountDown('#deal2', '05/24/2014', '22:59', {order: 2, spacer: ''}) );  
    deals.push( new BK_CountDown('#deal3', '05/24/2014', '12:59', {order: 2, spacer: ''}) );  
    deals.push( new BK_CountDown('#deal4', '05/24/2014', '13:49', {order: 2, spacer: ''}) );  
    deals.push( new BK_CountDown('#deal5', '05/24/2014', '14:49', {order: 2, spacer: ''}) );  
    deals.push( new BK_CountDown('#deal6', '05/24/2014', '15:57', {order: 2, spacer: ''}) );  
    deals.push( new BK_CountDown('#deal7', '05/24/2014', '15:58', {order: 2, spacer: ''}) );  
    deals.push( new BK_CountDown('#deal8', '05/24/2014', '15:59', {order: 2, spacer: ''}) );  
    deals.push( new BK_CountDown('#deal9', '05/24/2014', '16:00', {order: 2, spacer: ''}) );  


    var dealcounter = setInterval(function(){ // create one setTimeout
        if (deals.length){
            for (i in deals){
                var selfobject = deals[i];
                selfobject.count_update();
                if(selfobject.complete == true) delete deals[i]; // remove from array 
            }
        }else{
            clearTimeout(dealcounter); // no more to count down, stop this loop
        }
    }, 5000); // 5 seconds

});
```

Comment: No, the HTML is changing again, every second. Your first answer was enough.                                                               

this.count_update();(function()                                     

http://jsfiddle.net/uJk73/4/

I'm not sure of this is okay but in console i dont get warnings or errors.

Comment: The text is updated every time. The appends only happen once. ^ That answer is my first answer - one setTimeout. You could make the text only change if it's actually different to what exists, but I wonder if the DOM has that check anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, now you bring me confused... The code above, i place it in my webshop product html, but he does not want it. I get no errors or warnings just the countdown doesn't showing up and not sure what you said about this happens only once time. I tried the code above (first answer) and tested it with many products (109) and it works.